# Scala generic subtype parameters

Tags: scala, generics, subtyping

Why does the compiler treat t1 ++ t2 result as List[Any]? Concatenating two Lists of type S should return a list of type S only.

```
// compiles
def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S = t1 

// type mismatch; found List[Any] required S
def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S = t1 ++ t2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I believe is happening. First of all, `S` ***is*** the same type everywhere, there is no magic here. Let's look at the first example:

```
scala> def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S = if(t1.isEmpty) t1 else t2
cons: [S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S)S

scala> cons(List(1), List(2.0))
res21: List[AnyVal] = List(2.0)
```

As you can see Scala correctly found the closest common ancestor for `Int` and `Double`, and it's `AnyVal`. So in this case `S` is `AnyVal`.

Now let's try this:

```
scala> def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S = t1 ++ t2
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: S
       def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S = t1 ++ t2
                                                      ^
```

What's wrong? This error message means that the result of `++` is somehow `List[Any]` instead of expected `S`. Why is that? Let's look at `++` signature (simplified, real signature is longer):

```
def ++[B >: A](other: List[B]): List[B] = ???
```

So Scala needs to find the closest ancestor of `A` and the actual type parameter of `other`. The only problem is: it needs to find `B` at the point where you define `cons`, not where you apply it later (`B` is not a free parameter for `cons`). The only information is the upper bound of `S`, and it's `List[Any]`, so the only safe solution for `B` at the point of definition of `cons` is the most generic one, i.e. `Any`. Which means that the result of `++` is `List[Any]`, and it doesn't fit `S`. Hence the error.

Third example:

```
scala> def cons[S <: Any](t1: List[S], t2: List[S]): List[S] = t1 ++ t2
cons: [S](t1: List[S], t2: List[S])List[S]

scala> cons(List(1), List(1.0))
res0: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 1.0)
```

Why does this work? Here both `t1` and `t2` have exactly the same type, no matter what `S` is (and `S` can be inferred later). So `B == S` and the result is `List[S]`. Again in this particular case `S` is the closest common ancestor of `Int` and `Double`.

Comment: In your third example you say "Here both t1 and t2 have exactly the same type, no matter what S is ". How can that be? List[Int] List[Double] are of different types arent they?

Comment: I think the confusion arises because different types can be initially passed in as arguments but the type for S will be the nearest common ancestor of the different types passed.

Comment: I second @Samar's questions. I don't see a difference between `(t1: S, t2: S)` and `(t1: List[S], t2: List[S])`. In both cases t1 and t2 have the exact same type. Sure, you can pass `List[Int]` and `List[String]`, but in that case closest ancestor is `List[Any]` so that's what `S` is. Can you provide an example for `def cons[S <: List[Any]](t1: S, t2: S): S` where we would have an error (hence the compiler doesn't allow it)? Whatever you pass in, compiler will infer `S` to be the closest ancestor and **that's what will be returned**. Inferred type `S`. It should work with `S` then, no?

Comment: @Samar When I say "the same type" it doesn't mean that actual runtime types are the same, it means that when you "instantiate" your method, i.e. call `cons(List(1), List(2.0))` Scala will infer it as `cons(t1: List[AnyVal], t2: List[AnyVal]): List[AnyVal]`, and while you in fact passed `List[Int]` and `List[Double]` `cons` only operates with `List[AnyVal]`

Comment: @slouc What you described is what works in the first example. I wish I would fully understand why Scala can't infer `B` in the second one, but it seems that going back from `S` to its parameter is not implemented, as opposed to the third example where `S` is explicitly mentioned and `B` can be easily inferred.

Answer (score 1):

`List[Any] ++ List[Any]` is a `List[Any]` does not guarantee `S`, a subtype of `List[Any]` also have the property of `S ++ S` is a `S`, so the complier falls back to `List[Any]`.

Comment: i think Victor's answer really clarifies whats going on. I am not 100% sure yet, but I think when the two actual arguments t1/t2 are passed to the cons method, the types of the passed in arguments are traced back to their nearest common ancestor and that is the type of S. Not the passed in type of the argument.